# FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

I was just working with FormsAuthentication and I wanted the value of timeout property of form authentication tag in web config. In 4.0 we can get this via FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes (ref: [FormsAuthenticationTicket.expiration v web.config value timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171637/formsauthenticationticket-expiration-v-web-config-value-timeout)) Can you let me know how can I get the same in .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [this issue on Microsoft's Connect site](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/102290/expose-forms-authentication-timeout-as-a-public-static-property).  It was closed as "Won't Fix", but it looks like it's been fixed in .NET 4.

One way of doing it in .NET 2.0 or 3.x is to issue and inspect a FormsAuthentication ticket:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("user", false);
HttpCookie cookie = (HttpCookie)(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]);
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
int timeoutInMinutes = (ticket.Expiration - ticket.IssueDate).TotalMinutes;
```

Another is to use the configuration APIs:

```
Configuration config = Configuration.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath);
AuthenticationSection section = 
    (AuthenticationSection)config.GetSection("system.web/authentication");
int timeout = section.Forms.Timeout.TotalMinutes;
```